# Android: Having trouble getting View in a ViewGroup used to create ListView row layouts

Tags: android, view, android-listview, android-imageview, viewgroup

I have a ListView with a custom layout for the rows (list items) and the list is being populated with an adapter as usual. In this custom layout, I've added an ImageView and TextView (so there's an icon to match the text). I'm unable to get the ImageView based on the position in the ListView (Need to do this so I can set the icon to match the text obviously)and the only real information I get from the error log is the line the error is on but I'll post it anyways. Any help is greatly appreciated. I really don't want to create a mess by having to remove the ListView, create a bunch of RelativeLayouts, encompass them in a LinearLayout and put that inside a Scrollview.

Relevant Code:-

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.servicelist);
String[] values = new String[] { "Choice0", "Choice1", "Choice2",
        "Choice3", "Choice4", "Choice5" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.services_row,
android.R.id.text1, values);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

for(int position=0; position<11; position++){
    ViewGroup rowView = (ViewGroup) listView.getChildAt(position);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.service_row_icon); //ERROR HERE
    switch(position){
    case 0:{ icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); break; }
    case 1:{ icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); break; }
    //ETC ETC More cases go here, irrelevant code
    }
}
```

Row layout (service_row.xml):-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/service_row_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/service_row_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error log:-

```
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dragonheart.autodroid/com.dragonheart.autodroid.ServiceClasses.AddServiceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at com.dragonheart.autodroid.ServiceClasses.AddServiceActivity.onCreate(AddServiceActivity.java:43)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
06-28 01:46:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(18070):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Whenever your app crashes, you **really** should post your full logcat trace.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to do so, slipped my mind, thanks for reminding me ^^

Comment: To be clear: is `ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.service_row_icon);` line 40?

Comment: Nope, it's line 43. i.e. The line which is causing the error according to the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that inside your `getView` of your adapter, not outside of it.  It crashes because the framework  doesn't have a clue which of the many views in your list that you want.

Inside the adapter, it will know the position and be able to return the proper view.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks, I'll try it out and let you know how it turns out ASAP.

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. The exact solution is a little too long for me to post here so unfortunately, I'll just have to post a link to it instead in case anybody wants it but really this answer is enough to fix the issue. Thanks again! Link:- http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html